# Combine text fields as shown in Windows 7 Calculator

Tags: java, swing, awt, textfield, custom-component

How can I make a 'combined' Text Field (outlined in red, below) as shown in Windows Calculator?

[image: Combined output field in Windows 7 Calculator]

Comment: what is a combine text field?

Comment: I want make Calculator in java so for calc screen i need combine text field?

Comment: yeah =) I'm asking again, what is a combine text field? Explain it please.

Comment: In Win7, Calc Text Field divided into two section upper section show expression and lower section show to us value which we enter. This thing i want.

Comment: The Window calculator has an input area with an 'calculation in-progress' display area on top. Simply create a component in a new container with a `JLabel` for the display and a `JTextField` for the input.

Comment: @ivanovic Good question.  1) See screen-shot 2) Neither field is focusable, though right click produces a context menu for `Copy`, `Paste` & `Show  History` (which expands a navigable list above the **789** label in place of the smaller label).  -- It turns out it is quite a complex component!  (Though I expect the OP is thinking purely of the combination shown above.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of those fields is focusable.  Two labels stacked on top of each other should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the Window calculator has an input area with an 'calculation in-progress' at the bottom of the container and a display area on top of it (where it displays the input number sequence). Simply create a component in a new container (for example JPanel) and fill it with a JTextField for the display and a JTextField for the input data. Make the borders 'no' and the background color 'white' for two JTextFields Do it so for the container but gives any border and color you want for it.

Answer (score -1):

I forgot it before. I mainly spoke about NetBeans but the same happens manually.
If you are interested about a costruction of calculator go to the following site:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVYH8MEaQ1U
where you can download it.
And the site on the youtube where he shows the construction of the application:
http://www.mediafire.com/?nde1i53tdyqc8tc